# Player sign interact

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, sign

I want to code a plugin for a plugin's bug.(ChestShop).
When player right click sign(Sign's line 2 is "B Free" or "Free" and line 3 is "Iron_Ingot") cancel event and send message.

```
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e){
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    if(e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) || e.getAction().equals(Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK) ){
        if(e.getClickedBlock().getState() instanceof Sign){
            Sign sign = (Sign) e.getClickedBlock().getState();
            if(sign.getLine(2).equals("B Free") || sign.getLine(2).equals("Free")){
                if(sign.getLine(3).equals("Iron_Ingot"))
                e.setCancelled(true);
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage("You can not click this sign");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work, which part of the code is wrong?
What methods can I use?

Comment: What is Block.getState()?

Comment: Specify Sign which block use it.

Comment: You forgot the `@EventHandler` ?
Also make sure you have events registered.

Comment: You also have to `implements Listener` and register it in your plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class your method onPlayerInteract is in has to implement te interface Listener. You also have to use the EventHandler annotation and register the event in your plugin.

```
public class PlayerInteract implements Listener {

    // priority is when the listener is called.
    // LOWEST is called first, then LOW, NORMAL, HIGH, HIGHEST, MONITOR.
    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.NORMAL)
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

In your onEnable in the Main class (which extends JavaPlugin):

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerInteract(),this);
```

Comment: Don't worry, i know how to use any event(EventHandler enum or Main java class implement  ... ) but i didn't find out this

Comment: @drhopeness If it still doesn't work, post your full class where you handle the event, your Main class, plugin.yml and any errors.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed bug.